# Testing VrfCoordinatorV2Mock fulfillRandomWords gets stuck

Tags: solidity, ether, javascript, hardhat, vrf

I am testing a smart contract that uses Chainlink's VRF Oracle. Locally, I am using a mock to test with. In the unit test it never executes the `fulfillRandomWords` function that on my smart contract, which is supposed to be executed after the `VrfCoordinatorV2` runs its own `fulfillRandomWords`.

All the other tests pass except the last one it just gets stuck until it times out.

Here are the tests (my test file is a bit big, so I removed irrelevant tests):

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers, deployments, network } = require('hardhat');
const { devChains, networkConfig } = require('../../network.config');

!devChains.includes(network.name) ?
describe.skip : 
describe('RAYC', function () {
  let randomApeYachtClub, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, deployer;
  const mintFee = networkConfig[network.config.chainId].mintFee;

  beforeEach(async function() {
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    deployer = accounts[0];
    await deployments.fixture(['mocks', 'RAYC']);

    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock");
    randomApeYachtClub = await ethers.getContract("RandomApeYachtClub");
  });

  describe('fulfillRandomWords', function() {
    it('reverts if no valid requestId is provided', async function () {
      await expect(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(0, randomApeYachtClub.address)).to.be.revertedWith('nonexistent request');
    });

    it('emits RandomWordsFulfilled', async function () {
      // mint NFT
      const tx = await randomApeYachtClub.mintNft({ value: mintFee });
      const receipt = await tx.wait(1);
      const requestId = receipt.events.find(e => e.event === 'NFTRequested').args['requestId'];
      // call fulfillRandomWords
      // and watch for the event
      await expect(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, randomApeYachtClub.address))
      .to.emit(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, 'RandomWordsFulfilled');
    });

    it('the vrf fulfillRandomWords sends the randomWords and emits NFTMinted', async function () {
      await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        randomApeYachtClub.on('NFTMinted', () => {
          try {
            // This right here is never executed
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(erro);
          }
        });
        try {
          // mint NFT
          const tx = await randomApeYachtClub.mintNft({ value: mintFee });
          const receipt = await tx.wait(1);
          const requestId = receipt.events.find(e => e.event === 'NFTRequested').args['requestId'];
          // call fulfillRandomWords
          // and watch for the event
          await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, randomApeYachtClub.address);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my smart contract (again I removed irrelevant code, for the sake of simplicity)

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

error RandomApeYachtClub__NotOwner();
error RandomApeYachtClub__BreedNotFound();
error RandomApeYachtClub__NotEnoughFeeToMint();
error RandomApeYachtClub__NotAbleToWithdraw();

contract RandomApeYachtClub is ERC721URIStorage, VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
  enum ApeBreed {
    CHIMP,
    GORILLA,
    BABOON,
    BLACK_HOWLER
  }

  // VRF helpers
  VRFCoordinatorV2Interface immutable private COORDINATOR;
  address immutable private i_vrfCoordinator;
  bytes32 immutable private i_keyHash;
  uint32 immutable private i_callbackGasLimit;
  uint64 immutable private i_subscriptionId;
  mapping (uint256 => address) s_requestIdToMinter;

  // NFT helper
  uint256 constant private MAX_RARITY = 500;
  uint256 private s_tokenId;
  string[4] private s_tokenURIs;
  mapping (uint256 => string) tokenIdToTokenURI;

  uint256 private i_mintFee;
  address immutable private i_owner;

  // Events
  event NFTRequested(uint256 requestId, address sender);
  event NFTMinted(uint256 requestId, uint256 tokenId, ApeBreed breed, address minter);

  constructor (
    address vrfCoordinator,
    bytes32 keyHash,
    uint32 callbackGasLimit,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    string[4] memory tokenURIs,
    uint256 mintFee
  )
  ERC721("RandomApeYachtClub", "RAYC")
  VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator)
  {
    i_owner = msg.sender;
    COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
    i_vrfCoordinator = vrfCoordinator;
    i_keyHash = keyHash;
    i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
    i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    s_tokenURIs = tokenURIs;
    i_mintFee = mintFee;
  }
  
  // ETH fee to mint, random nft minted
  function mintNft() payable external returns (uint256 requestId) {
    if(msg.value < i_mintFee)
      revert RandomApeYachtClub__NotEnoughFeeToMint();

    requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
      i_keyHash,
      i_subscriptionId,
      3,
      i_callbackGasLimit,
      1
    );

    s_requestIdToMinter[requestId] = msg.sender;
    emit NFTRequested(requestId, msg.sender);
  }

  // randomness
  function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
    address minter = s_requestIdToMinter[requestId];
    uint256 tokenId = s_tokenId;

    uint256 randomNumber = randomWords[0] % MAX_RARITY;
    ApeBreed apeBreed = getApeFromNumber(randomNumber);
    string memory _tokenURI = s_tokenURIs[uint256(apeBreed)];
    _safeMint(minter, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    tokenIdToTokenURI[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    s_tokenId++;
    emit NFTMinted(requestId, tokenId, apeBreed, minter);
  }

  function getApeFromNumber(uint256 randomNumber) public pure returns (ApeBreed) {
    uint256[4] memory rarityChance = getRarityChance();
    uint256 accu = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < rarityChance.length; i++) {
      if((randomNumber >= rarityChance[i]) && (randomNumber < (rarityChance[i] + accu))) {
        return ApeBreed(i);
      }
      accu += rarityChance[i];
    }
    revert RandomApeYachtClub__BreedNotFound();
  }

  function getRarityChance() internal pure returns (uint256[4] memory) {
    return [10, 30, 120, MAX_RARITY];
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
await expect(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, randomApeYachtClub.address))
      .to.emit(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, 'RandomWordsFulfilled');
```

I assume above line is failed?

There could be a number of possible reasons to fail to emit `RandomWordsFulfilled` event.

If you look into to VRFCoordinatorV2Mock's fulfillRandomWordsWithOverride function, there seems to be 3 possible revert happens.

```
if (s_requests[_requestId].subId == 0) {
  revert("nonexistent request");  // First one
}
....
} else if (_words.length != req.numWords) {
  revert InvalidRandomWords();    // Second one
}
....
if (s_subscriptions[req.subId].balance < payment) {
  revert InsufficientBalance();    // Third one
}
```

So, my guess is, first, check if you setup mock correctly, e.g: add enough funds, add consumer correctly, set callback gas limit correctly, etc.

And second is, you can do

```
import "hardhat/console.sol"

console.log(...)
```

in your solidity code to debug line by line to track down the problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` has no logic inside so you have to implement it yourself. You also need to create the subscription, fund it with enough LINK and register your contract as a consumer.

NOTE: In the following code, you should replace `MyContract` by your contract, the method `generate` by your method that requests the random numbers and `Generated` by the events raised once the random numbers are handled.

NOTE: The following code uses features from [TypeChain](https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain) and [hardhat-deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy).

First you need to deploy both the `LinkToken` and the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` contracts but only if deploying to localhost. I use the following `000_Mocks.ts` script:

```typescript
import {DeployFunction} from 'hardhat-deploy/types';

const POINT_ONE_LINK = '100000000000000000';

const func: DeployFunction = async ({
    deployments,
    getNamedAccounts,
    getChainId,
}) => {
    const {deploy, log} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId = await getChainId();

    if (chainId == '1337') {
        log('Local network detected! Deploying mocks...');

        log('Deploying LinkToken...');

        await deploy('LinkToken', {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            autoMine: true, // speed up deployment on local network (ganache, hardhat), no effect on live networks
        });

        log('Deploying VRFCoordinatorV2Mock...');

        await deploy('VRFCoordinatorV2Mock', {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [
                POINT_ONE_LINK,
                1e9, // 0.000000001 LINK per gas
            ],
            autoMine: true, // speed up deployment on local network (ganache, hardhat), no effect on live networks
        });
    }
};
export default func;
func.tags = ['all', 'mocks'];
```

I pass all the required data as constructor parameters to my contract. One of the parameters is the `subscriptionId`. The script `010_MyContract.ts`, creates the subscription and deposits 10 LINK before deploying the contract. Once the contract is deployed, the contract is added as a consumer to the subscription.

```typescript
import {ethers, network} from 'hardhat';
import {DeployFunction} from 'hardhat-deploy/types';
import {
    ChainlinkVrfPropsStruct,
} from '../build/typechain/src/MyContract';
import {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} from '../helper-hardhat-config';
import {VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory} from '../build/typechain/factories/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory';

const TEN_LINK = '10000000000000000000';

const func: DeployFunction = async ({
    deployments,
    getNamedAccounts,
    getChainId,
}) => {
    const {deploy, get, log} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId = await getChainId();
    
    const config = networkConfig[chainId];
    let chainlink: ChainlinkVrfPropsStruct = config.chainlink;
    let waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS;

    if (chainId == '1337') {
        const linkTokenDeployment = await get('LinkToken');
        const VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment = await get(
            'VRFCoordinatorV2Mock',
        );

        const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();
        const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory.connect(
            VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address,
            signer,
        );

        // create VRF subscription
        const subscriptionCreationReceipt = await (
            await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        ).wait();
        const subscriptionId = subscriptionCreationReceipt.events![0].topics[1];

        chainlink = {
            ...chainlink,
            keyHash: ethers.constants.HashZero,
            subscriptionId: subscriptionId,
            vrfCoordinatorContract:
                VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address ??
                ethers.constants.AddressZero,
            linkTokenContract:
                linkTokenDeployment.address ?? ethers.constants.AddressZero,
        };
        waitBlockConfirmations = 0;
    }

    const args: any[] = [
        chainlink,
    ];

    /**
     * Validate Fields
     */
    if (!chainlink) throw new Error('Missing chainlink');
    if (chainlink.subscriptionId === 0)
        throw new Error('Missing chainlink subscriptionId');
    if (!chainlink.linkTokenContract)
        throw new Error('Missing chainlink linkTokenContract');
    if (!chainlink.keyHash) throw new Error('Missing chainlink keyHash');
    if (!chainlink.vrfCoordinatorContract)
        throw new Error('Missing chainlink vrfCoordinatorContract');
    if (!chainlink.minimumRequestConfirmations)
        throw new Error('Missing chainlink minimumRequestConfirmations');

    log('Deploying MyContract...');

    const result = await deploy('MyContract', {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
        autoMine: true, // speed up deployment on local network (ganache, hardhat), no effect on live networks
        //deterministicDeployment: true,
        gasLimit: 8_000_000,
    });

    if (chainId == '1337') {
        const VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment = await get(
            'VRFCoordinatorV2Mock',
        );

        const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();
        const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory.connect(
            VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address,
            signer,
        );

        // add consumer
        await (
            await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(
                chainlink.subscriptionId,
                result.address,
            )
        ).wait();

        // fund the VRF subscription
        await (
            await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(
                chainlink.subscriptionId,
                TEN_LINK,
            )
        ).wait();
    }
};
export default func;
func.tags = ['all', 'MyContract'];
```

This deployment script gets the configurations from a `helper-hardhat-config.ts` file:

```typescript
import {ethers} from 'hardhat';

const networkConfig: any = {
    default: {
        name: 'hardhat',
    },
    1337: {
        name: 'localhost',
        chainlink: {
            keyHash:
                '0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc',
            minimumRequestConfirmations: 3,
        },
    },
    5: {
        name: 'goerli',
        // https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
        chainlink: {
            subscriptionId: 6918,
            vrfCoordinatorContract:
                '0x2ca8e0c643bde4c2e08ab1fa0da3401adad7734d',
            linkTokenContract: '0x326c977e6efc84e512bb9c30f76e30c160ed06fb',
            keyHash:
                '0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15',
            minimumRequestConfirmations: 3,
        },
    },
    1: {
        // https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
        chainlink: {
            subscriptionId: 1696,
            vrfCoordinatorContract:
                '0x271682DEB8C4E0901D1a1550aD2e64D568E69909',
            linkTokenContract: '0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca',
            keyHash:
                '0x8af398995b04c28e9951adb9721ef74c74f93e6a478f39e7e0777be13527e7ef',
            minimumRequestConfirmations: 5,
        },
    },
};

const developmentChains = ['hardhat', 'localhost'];
const VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS = 6;

export {networkConfig, developmentChains, VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS};
```

Now that all the required contracts have been deployed, lets setup the units tests.

```typescript
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {MyAccessControl, MyContract} from '../build/typechain';
import {VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory} from '../build/typechain/factories/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory';
import {MyAccessControl__factory} from '../build/typechain/factories/src/MyAccessControl__factory';
import {MyPaymentSplitter__factory} from '../build/typechain/factories/src/MyPaymentSplitter__factory';
import {MyContract__factory} from '../build/typechain/factories/src/MyContract__factory';
import {SignerWithAddress} from '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers';
const {deployments} = require('hardhat');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fixtures

const userData = (
    signer: SignerWithAddress,
    myContract: MyContract,
) => {
    return {
        signer: signer,
        myContract: myContract.connect(signer),
    };
};

// this fixture deploys the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock and MyContract contracts
const fixtureDeployed = deployments.createFixture(
    async ({deployments, ethers}) => {
        const {get} = deployments;
        await deployments.fixture(['all']);
        const vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployment = await get(
            'VRFCoordinatorV2Mock',
        );
        const myContractDeployment = await get('MyContract');
        const [deployer, user] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock__factory.connect(
            vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address,
            deployer,
        );

        const myContract = MyContract__factory.connect(
            myContractDeployment.address,
            deployer,
        );

        return {
            vrfCoordinatorV2Mock,
            myContract,
            deployer: userData(deployer, myContract),
            user: userData(user, myContract),
        };
    },
);

// this fixture calls the generate() method and waits for the Generated event to be emitted
const fixtureGenerated = deployments.createFixture(async () => {
    // wait for the contract to be deployed
    const {myContract, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, ...fixture} = await fixtureDeployed();

    // the random number is generated asynchronouly so
    // this promise registers to the events, calls generate() and 
    // resolves once flow ends
    const waitGenerated = () =>
        new Promise<void>(resolve => {
            // declare event listeners
            const onRandomWordsRequested: TypedListener<
                RandomWordsRequestedEvent
            > = (
                _keyHash: string,
                requestId: BigNumber,
                _preSeed: BigNumber,
                _subId: BigNumber,
                _minimumRequestConfirmations: number,
                _callbackGasLimit: number,
                _numWords: number,
                sender: string,
            ) => {
                // unregister this event listener
                vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.removeListener(
                    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.filters.RandomWordsRequested(),
                    onRandomWordsRequested,
                );
                // simulate callback from the oracle network
                vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, sender);
            };

            const onGenerated: TypedListener<GeneratedEvent> = (
                _sender: string,
                _value: BigNumber,
            ) => {
                // unregister this event listener
                myContract.removeListener(
                    myContract.filters.Generated(),
                    onGenerated,
                );
                // Generated event has been emitted
                resolve();
            };

            // register event listeners
            vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.on(
                vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.filters.RandomWordsRequested(),
                onRandomWordsRequested,
            );
            myContract.on(
                myContract.filters.Generated(), 
                onGenerated);

            // call generate()
            fixture.deployer.myContract.generate();
        });

    // call generate() and wait for Generated event to be emitted
    await waitGenerated();

    return {
        ...fixture,
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock,
        myContract,
    };
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Tests

describe('MyContract tests', () => {

    describe('Reveal transactions', () => {
        it('Should successfully generate a random number', async () => {
            const {deployer} = await fixtureGenerated();

            // TODO: assert that the value generated has been correctly handled
            
        }).timeout(60_000);

    });
});
```

The test uses a fixture defined in the method `fixtureGenerated`. This fixture simply awaits for the method `waitGenerated` that emulates the controller behaviour missing in the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` implementation.

The method uses a `Promise` with a lambda expression which registers handlers for the the event `RandomWordsRequested` emitted by the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` instance and the event `Generated` by the `MyContract` instance. It then calls the `generate` method from the `MyContract` instance which calls the `requestRandomWords`. This raises the `RandomWordsRequested` from the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` instance.

The `onRandomWordsRequested` handler calls the `fulfillRandomWords` method from the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` instance which then calls the method with the same name in all the registered consumers.

The method `fulfillRandomWords` in the `MyContract` instance emits a `Generated` event which is then handled by the `onGenerated` method. This handler then resolves the `Promise` and the unit test can continue its flow.

NOTE: To make TypeChain generate the typescript wrappers for `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` and `LinkToken` just add the following files to your contracts folder:

LinkToken.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "@chainlink/token/contracts/v0.4/LinkToken.sol";
```

VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol";
```

It's intricate but I hope this helps.